# How to write unit test for googollee socket.io handlers

Tags: unit-testing, go, socket.io

I am using a go lib: github.com/googollee/go-socket.io
I am wondering how to write a very simple  test for connection event, ex, if i want to check no error is returned.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func main() {
    server := socketio.NewServer(nil)

    server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        fmt.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this test be part of `github.com/googollee/go-socket.io` itself and not userland code?

Comment: the code above is just an example, what if I have my own business logic inside of the handler, ex, db operations, or returning other values.

Comment: Create a seperate function which takes the `socketio.Conn` interface as a parameter, and pass that to `server.OnConnect` instead of an anonymous function. Then you can mock the `socketio.Conn` to unit test your function.

Comment: would u mind providing some code snippet that can help me understand, appreciate it .

Comment: Added sample snippet below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a seperate function which takes the socketio.Conn interface as a parameter, and pass that to `server.OnConnect` instead of an anonymous function.

Then you can mock the socketio.Conn to unit test your function.

For example, change your code snippet to:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func main() {
    server := socketio.NewServer(nil)

    server.OnConnect("/", handleOnConnect)
}

func handleOnConnect(s socketio.Conn) error {
    s.SetContext("")
    fmt.Println("connected:", s.ID())
    return nil
}
```

Now, all you have to do is test `handleOnConnect`. Because `socketio.Conn` is an interface, you can create a mock to test this function without worrying about `socketio` internals.

You can also create a new interface which is a subset of `socketio.Conn` depending on your use case to make mocking easier.